# Requesting Custom Fields from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I think there is a better name for what I am trying to do.

I have this.

```
SELECT * FROM user_bans WHERE user_id='{$user->id}'
```

What I want is something like this.

```
SELECT *, active = (DATE(expire) > NOW() ? 1 : 0) FROM user_bans WHERE user_id='{$user->id}'
```

The expire field is a datetime field. I want to see if the ban has expired and set the active value accordingly.

What syntax do I need to use to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This might be your need!

```
SELECT *, IF(DATE(expire) > CURDATE() , 1 , 0) AS `active` 
FROM user_bans WHERE user_id={$user->id}
```

Comment: IF() is definitely what he was looking for.  However, I would also correct a few of his problems (he's comparing a date to NOW(), should be compared to CURDATE() - and if user_id is an integer, {$user->id} should not be enclosed in single-quotes)